# Azure Functions questions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

So a colleague has left the enterprise I work for and I have to take some of the projects he was in charge.
One project is based on Azure Functions (v1) but I don't quite understand it all.

The point of the project is to run some code on databases every night (statistics, rebuild indexes, ...)

So it is organized this way

```
RunTimerTrigger([TimerTrigger("0 30 0 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
    For each database: starter.StartNewAsync(DurableTenantFunction, tenantInfo);

[FunctionName(DurableTenantFunction)]
RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContextBase context,
            [Queue(FunctionConstants.DurableMidnightScriptQueue, Connection = "ServerFunctionsStorage")]
    Call activity 1 (context.CallActivityAsync)
    Call activity 2
    Call activity 3
    //Put message in queue to start trigger the scripts for the DB
    await outputQueue.AddAsync(tenantInfo);

RunOrchestratorClient([QueueTrigger(FunctionConstants.DurableMidnightScriptQueue)] TenantInfo tenantInfo,
        [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter
    Call activity 4
    Call activity 5
    Call activity 6
```

So we have a TimerTrigger that fire every night at 0:30. It get the database we have to update and then run an orchestrator. The orchestrator call some activites and then add a message in a queue.
This queue trigger another OrchestratorClient that fire three mores activities. (Orchestrator 1 is mostly update of stats and orchestrator 2 mostly optimization of db (sleeping session, index, ...)

We noticed that there were something strange in the behavior of our midnight-script (it's the name we call this part of code) and so i add some logs to check behavior. Logs are like this

```
//Log start activity 1 for database x
start activity 1
// Log end activity 1 for database x
// Log start activity 2 for database x
...
```

Based on the logs the timer trigger each night like it is supposed to, but then there is very strange behavior within the orchestrator, we have like hundred start activity 1 but not as many end activity 1. And the activity 4,5,6 are not reached like one night over two on our largest database.

Have you guys any idea of what is happening? Have you some lead on a better architecture using functions to run some codes every night on databases?

If you have some other questions, don't hesitate to ask

Thanks a lot

Comment: This I believe is a good way of doing it. Coming to the problem at hand, I believe the `RunOrchestratorClient` should be starting other orchestrators and not activity functions. Right? Also, for more insights on whats happening, you could try checking the [azure storage queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#internal-queue-triggers) to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Logging in durable functions can be quite weird.  To quote the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#reliability)

> When an orchestration function is given more work to do (for example, a response message is received or a durable timer expires), the orchestrator wakes up and re-executes the entire function from the start to rebuild the local state. During the replay, if the code tries to call a function (or do any other async work), the Durable Task Framework consults the execution history of the current orchestration. If it finds that the activity function has already executed and yielded a result, it replays that function's result and the orchestrator code continues to run. Replay continues until the function code is finished or until it has scheduled new async work.

This "replay" behavior has some ramifications for logging.  In particular, if an orchestrator function emits log messages, the replay behavior may cause duplicate log messages to be emitted.  Give this [durable functions logging example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics#logging) a quick read.

It's quite possible you are seeing duplicate log messages because of this.